# Deactivating a page from host server

Tags: php, rename

I want to deactivate a page from my hosting. like
www. example.com/page5.php
If i type above link in browser. It shows me 404 page or redirect me on main page etc.

How to do this please guid me. while i don't want to rename the page.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "deactivate" exactly? Please add more detail and context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^page5.php$ index.php [R=404,L]
```

or in page5.php

```
header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
```

or

```
header('Location: index.php');
```

or

```
header('Refresh: 2; url=index.php');
print "You are not allowed to access this page.";
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
Header(Location: URL);
```

Or:

```
die("You cant acces this page");
```

Or:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
exit;
```